# Pagination with next and previous button and only show 5 pages on load in HTML table using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I got a no. of pages but I want to restrict it by showing 5 pages on load with next and previous buttons [which shows pages number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3idLS.png).

**My code is:**

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var totalRows = $('#MyTable').find('tbody tr:has(td)').length;
      var recordPerPage = 10;
      var totalPages = Math.ceil(totalRows / recordPerPage);
      var $pages = $('<div id="pages"></div>');
      var $previous = $('<span class="previous"><<</spnan>');
      var $next = $('<span class="next">>></spnan>');
      for (i = 0; i < totalPages; i++) {
         $('<span>' + (i + 1) + '</span>').appendTo($pages);     
      }
      $pages.appendTo('#MyTable');

      $('#MyTable').find('tbody tr:has(td)').hide();
      var tr = $('#MyTable tbody tr:has(td)');
      for (var i = 0; i <= recordPerPage-1; i++) {
          $(tr[i]).show();
      }
      $('span').click(function(event) {
        $('#MyTable').find('tbody tr:has(td)').hide();
        var nBegin = ($(this).text() - 1) * recordPerPage;
        var nEnd = $(this).text() * recordPerPage - 1;
        for (var i = nBegin; i <= nEnd; i++)
        {
          $(tr[i]).show();
        }
      });
    });
    </script>
```

**I've made my pagination like:**
 "first previous 1 2 3 4 5 next last"

I hope you guys understand?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you looked at datatables? https://datatables.net/

Comment: actually this code i used in modal.This code is working fine only i have to add that functionality in this code only i have other code which is working as i want but for this i have to edit my code many times because i used it in mostly pages if it is possible to add this functionality in this code then its good

Comment: @Odyssey 1111 i used datatables as you told but it show all record instead of some records and break it in to pages.I used js and css file also

Answer (score 1):

> Hi,  You can create simple pagination using the TWBS pagination JS
>   library. here is a quick example of pagination on codepen it might
>   help you.
>
> ```
> example code on codepen
> ```
>
> https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/WprNwa/